# Two identical mysql tables, one is empty, how to populate it?

Tags: mysql, database

I have one table full of data (around 20,000 values)

```
table_1

ID | name | e-mail (only as an example, it could be just normal TEXT)
1  |alfaa | e-mail alfaa 1
2  |alfaa | e-mail alfaa 2
3  |beta  | e-mail beta
4  |celta | e-mail celta
...
```

and other identical table with the "e-mail" column empty, and some names that are also contained in table_1, alltough with a different ID

```
table_2 (around 5,000 values)

ID | name | e-mail
1  |beta  |
2  |alfaa |
3  |celta |
...
```

My question is, how can I populate the empty e-mail column of table_2 with values from e-mail column of table_1 WHERE table_2.name = table_1.name ?

The IDs are different AND table_1 contains some cases of several e-mails for the same name.

(well, I think I also could to manage it to work without several e-mails for the same name)

Comment: Do you have control over the structure of the database? Because if you do, you might want to consider [Database Normalization](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization).

Comment: How did you want to deal with the fact that some values in Table 1 are multiple going to a single row is available in Table 2? Also why are you replicating data? This is not generally considered good practise. Would a join not be more suitable?

Comment: @HansZ  Yes, I am the owner of the Server. Acyclic Tau: I'm doing this because I have a MASTER data base with lots of text, say SOURCE and DESTINY, and a SLAVE table, containing new text, but only SOURCE... In this case, I Need a comparation between table_1_SOURCE and table_2_SOURCE.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've got:

```
UPDATE table_2, table_1
SET table_2.email = table_1.email
WHERE table_1.name = table_2.name;
```

See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b99e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about [Database Normalization](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization).

You have found a problem in the way your database schema is designed, mainly, you're store a lot of data in multiple places. This can easily lead to tables drifting out of sync from each other, wasted storage space, and costly lookups.

Let me show you what I'm talking about.

---

### Case 1. Synchronizing tables.

Let's say you do populate your table_1, table_2 correctly. You get something like this:

```
table_1                        table_2

ID_1 | name | email            ID_2 | name | email
1    | bob  | bob@cat.com      1    | adam | adam@dog.com
2    | adam | adam@dog.com     2    | bob  | bob@cat.com
3    | bob  | bob@dog.com      3    | bob  | bob@dog.com
4    | joe  | joe@dog.com
```

Note that I'm storing bob's two emails twice. This might not seem like much but if bob has 5 emails, and you add a table_3, then you're storing 15 records to only refer to 5 unique pieces of information.

Now let's say you're adam, and you want to update your email, let's say you want to change your email to `adam@cat.com`. And you do it in program 1, which uses `table_1`, but you don't do it in program 2, which uses `table_2`. What do you get when you hit the update?

```
table_1                        table_2

ID_1 | name | email            ID_2 | name | email
1    | bob  | bob@cat.com      1    | adam | adam@dog.com
2    | adam | adam@cat.com     2    | bob  | bob@cat.com
3    | bob  | bob@dog.com      3    | bob  | bob@dog.com
4    | joe  | joe@dog.com
```

Adam now has a different email depending on whether he uses program 1 or program 2. So to solve this, you'd need to go through table_2 every time you change stuff in table_1, which is an extra database call.

---

### Case 2. Internal consistency

Now let's say bob wants to change his name to jill. What happens now?

```
table_1                        table_2

ID_1 | name | email            ID_2 | name | email
1    | jill | bob@cat.com      1    | adam | adam@dog.com
2    | adam | adam@dog.com     2    | bob  | bob@cat.com
3    | bob  | bob@dog.com      3    | bob  | bob@dog.com
4    | joe  | joe@dog.com
```

Oops, I accidentally only updated one row corresponding to bob in table 1, now it seems like bob@cat.com and bob@dog.com are two different people, when they actually are the same. So I'd have to go through the entire database and check every row for `name = "bob"`. Then I have to do the same for table_2. Your database is quickly becoming unmanageable.

---

### Database Normalization

Instead of having two tables.

```
table_1                        table_2

ID_1 | name | email            ID_2 | name | email
1    | bob  | bob@cat.com      1    | adam | adam@dog.com
2    | adam | adam@dog.com     2    | bob  | bob@cat.com
3    | bob  | bob@dog.com      3    | bob  | bob@dog.com
4    | joe  | joe@dog.com
```

Take the information common to the two tables, namely name-email pairs, and put it in a user table

```
table_1          table_2          user

ID_1 | userId    ID_2 | userId    userId | name | email
1    | 2         1    | 1         1      | adam | adam@dog.com
2    | 1         2    | 2         2      | bob  | bob@cat.com
3    | 2         3    | 2         2      | bob  | bob@dog.com
4    | 3                          3      | joe  | joe@dog.com
```

This fixes a lot of issues, now when you want to look up a user's name/email, you go look it up in a user table based off a userId. If adam changes his email, it changes for both tables (because they both refer to the user table).

There's still one more thing, if bob changes his name, we shouldn't have to look through the entire user table to change every occasion of his name. So we can take this one step further.

```
table_1          table_2          user              email

ID_1 | userId    ID_2 | userId    userId | name     userId | email
1    | 2         1    | 1         1      | adam     1      | adam@dog.com
2    | 1         2    | 2         2      | bob      2      | bob@cat.com
3    | 2         3    | 2         3      | joe      2      | bob@dog.com
4    | 3                                            3      | joe@dog.com
```

Now we have no pieces of information that are redundant, no need to duplicate values, and changes in any one place affects every other table that refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

@remram: Thanks, it works. I tried directly with PhpMyAdmin.

Some small modification:

```
UPDATE table_2, table_1
SET table_2.`email` = table_1.`email`
WHERE table_1.`name` = table_2.`name`;
```

@HansZ: Thank you also for the DataBase Normalization explanation.
In this case, remram solution is what I was needing. I was looking for a kind of Fuzzy VLOOKUP in MySQL, and this would be a way to get what I want

http://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/microsoft-fuzzy-lookup-add-in-for-excel-2010-walkthrough/

And here a small Explanation: I have a list of words that needs to be translated. Some of those words are already in the Master, and the Slave database is empty... At the end, I just need to translate the empty values